# Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class in ListFragment

Tags: android, list, android-listview, staggered-gridview

I am creating a StaggeredGridView using https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid . But when I try to initialze the StaggeredGridView like follows:-

```
 public class HomeFragment extends ListFragment 
{

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);




        mGridView =(StaggeredGridView)vi.findViewById(R.id.grid_view); // Issue here


        return vi;
    }
}
```

This is my Xml file:-

```
<com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/grid_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:item_margin="8dp"
app:column_count="3" />
```

I get the following error:-

```
06-09 09:07:16.568: E/AndroidRuntime(1836): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class
```

If I change the `ListFragment` to `Fragment` I get a NullPointerException while I try to set an adapter
What could be the cause?

Comment: Paste the code and point out the line.

Comment: @Aniruddha Please see my Edit. The Logcat does not show the line. But I think its while I initialize the mGridView